# Showing a Space-Filling Curve is Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology

**Setting:** Let $F':[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be the Cantor Function.

**Goal:** Show that there exists a well-defined, surjective, continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$ (i.e., a space-filling curve).

**Attempt:**

> ***EDIT:*** It turns out my function is non-sensical in that the domain isn't even $[0,1]$!  I'm leaving it here to show an attempt was
>   made at answering the question, but I've yet to come up with a
>   suitable candidate function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$.

1. Let $G: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$ s.t.

   $$
   G(x,y) = (F'(x),F'(y))
   $$
2. I claim that $G$ is a well-defined, surjective, continuous map.
3. First $G$ is clearly well-defined (there are no issues with representatives or equivalence classes).
4. To see that $G$ is surjective, let $(a,b) \in [0,1]^2$.
5. Consider $F'$ is surjective (I've already shown this on my own).
6. Hence we have that $\exists x,y \in [0,1]$ s.t. $F'(x) = a$ and $F'(y) = b$.
7. Then consider that $G(x,y) = (F'(x), F'(y)) = (a,b)$ so that $G$ is surjective as desired.

**Question:** Why is $G$ continuous?  I've shown elsewhere that $C \cong [0,1]$, and I've been given the hint that $C \cong C \times C$ would be a useful fact to prove.  Why would this fact be useful?

Comment: $G(x,y)=(F'(x),F'(y))$ defines a map $[0,1]\times[0,1]\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$, not $[0,1]\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: Did you really show $\mathcal C\cong [0,1]$? Because one of them is totally disconnected!

Comment: I showed $C \cong [0,1]$ in the cardinality sense.  Perhaps this was the wrong notation to use.

Comment: When talking about topological spaces, we usually reserve the symbol $\cong$ to mean *homeomorphic* rather than the weaker relation of them being *equinumerous* which is what it appears you're using the symbol for. It is the case that $\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}$ is **homeomorphic** to $\mathcal{C}$. That is, $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \cong \mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

The Cantor function $F':[0,1]\to[0,1]$ gives you a surjective continous map $F'|_{\mathcal C}:\mathcal C\to[0,1]$ from the Cantor set to the unit interval. Thus you can construct a surjective continuous map
$$
\mathcal C \overset\cong\longrightarrow \mathcal C\times\mathcal C \overset{F'|_{\mathcal C}\times F'|_{\mathcal C}}\longrightarrow [0,1]\times [0,1]
$$
and extend that to $[0,1]$. The extension can be done by linear interpolation explicitly or by applying the Tietze extension theorem.