When, if ever, can plane curves be dense subsets of a unit square?
Definitions of terms used in this question can be found here.
I think (?) that it is clear that an open (i.e. non-closed) (plane) curve can be a dense subset of $[0,1]\times [0,1].$
(Or is this already not true?)
I have a suspicion that a closed curve cannot be a dense subset of $[0,1]\times [0,1].$
However, one cannot say that this is due to the fact that a curve that is a dense subset of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ must have infinite arc length, because a closed curve can be fractal-like and easily have infinite arc length. Furthermore, it

So is my suspicion that a closed curve cannot be a dense subset of
$[0,1]\times [0,1]$ correct? And if so, what is the reason/proof for this?

I don't think requiring any of the above curves to be simple changes anything. [Or does it?]
I think these questions are unrelated to space-filling curves, which have iterations, whereas my question is not necessarily about iterations (although it might be).

But wouldn’t the adherence of a closed curve be the closed curve itself ? Maybe I’m being « dense » haha

Also I think that you can construct an open curve dense in the whole plane (I have a construction in mind) I’m less sure about higher dimensions but it should be doable as well

Look up "space-filling curve" on this website and on the web generally.

Do bear in mind that serious mathematicians once thought that "most" continuous functions from reals to reals were differentiable, and they were very badly wrong. Badly behaved functions are "generally" much more prevalent than well behaved functions (for most reasonable definitions of "well behaved"). Badly behaved functions are sometimes harder to construct, because our universe of construction on which we base our intuition is pretty "well behaved".

@julio_es_sui_glace "But wouldn’t the adherence of a closed curve be the closed curve itself ? " Sorry, but I don't know what this means. What do you mean by "adherence"?

@GerryMyerson obviously I have already done that, and my understanding is that a space filling curve is the limiting process of curves, each one filling up $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ more and more. However, I don't really get how this works, because then a space filling curve is not a curve itself: it is some sort of limiting process? But anyway, I could not find a good definition of "space-filling curve" anywhere.

The usual constructions of space-filling curves involve iteration, but the limiting figure is still a curve. Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688493/showing-a-space-filling-curve-is-continuous is helpful.

@AdamRubinson I meant that $\gamma(I)$ will be compact thus closed, thus you would have $\overline{\gamma(I)} = \gamma(I)$ no? Maybe I’m missing something

"Space-filling curve", no iteration: (1) Define a continuous surjection $C\to I$ where $C$ is the Cantor set and $I$ is the closed unit interval. (2) Use that to define a continuous surjection $C\times C\to I\times I$. (3) Define a continuous surjection $C\to C\times C$. (4) Compose the last two maps to get a continuous surjection $C\to I\times I$. (5) Extend that last map to a continuous surjection $I\to I\times I$. For steps (1) and (3) it may help to note that $C$ is homeomorphic to the product space $\prod_{n=1}^\infty{0,1}$.
